# Transparent mask is shown black

Tags: android

I am making mask for image. On most of my devices it works fine. Below is how I making it.

[image]

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/im_photo"
        android:layout_width="85dip"
        android:layout_height="64dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="85dip"
        android:layout_height="64dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_mask_background"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />
```

mask

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">


    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_patch" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_mask_selected" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_mask_selected" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_mask_selected" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_mask_selected" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_mask_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_mask_unselected" />

</selector>
```

rounded_mask_unselected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="-10dp"
        android:left="-10dp"
        android:right="-10dp"
        android:top="-10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="@color/dark_gray" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Unfortunatly on some devices (eg Galaxy Tab 7.7) my mask is completle black (if I remove it, I see unmask image)
[image]
How can I fix it?

Comment: I've seen effects like this related to hardware acceleration. I'd suggest experimenting with enabling/disabling hardware acceleration on the views.

Comment: @HexBugsAndSausageRolls alterating hardwareacceleration have not make an effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by different default color od different devices. Sometimes default color was transparent, sometime black. Solution - explisitly state the background.